# How to access web api method by using WebapiConfig?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i would like to access below methods but i can not access "http://www.test.com:46707/rpc/RealmStatus/RealmByPopulationName/2/Vindication"

```
    [ActionName("RealmByPopulationName")]
      public IEnumerable<MyRealmStatus> GetRealmsByBattleGroupName(int regionid, string battlegroupname)
      {
             //dosomething...
       }
```

My webApiConfig.cs below

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{regionid}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetData",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{regionid}/{id}"
        );


         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "RpcApi",
             routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{regionid}",
             defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "RpcApi2",
             routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{regionid}/{quality}/",
             defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RpcApi3",
            routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{regionid}/{battlegroupname}/",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
       );
    }
}
```

Error occurs i can not access GetRealmsByBattleGroupName

Result of "http://www.test.com:46707/rpc/RealmStatus/RealmByPopulationName/2/Vindication" :

```
<Error>
```

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.test.com:46707/rpc/RealmStatus/RealmByPopulationName/2/Vindication'.


No action was found on the controller 'RealmStatus' that matches the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is going to match this route first:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RpcApi2",
    routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{regionid}/{quality}/",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" }
);
```

Therefore your API is looking for a method on the RealmStatus controller that matches the following signature:

```
[ActionName("RealmByPopulationName")]
GetRealmsByBattleGroupName(int regionid, string quality)
```

If quality is a number you could differentiate the routes by adding the following constraint:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RpcApi2",
    routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{regionid}/{quality}/",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: new { id = @"(^\d+$)" }
);
```

Comment: public IEnumerable<MyRealmStatus> GetRealmsByBattleGroupName(int regionid, string BattleGroupName)  NOT working but,     public IEnumerable<MyRealmStatus> GetRealmsByBattleGroupName(int regionid, string quality)  is working. How to solve the problem...

Comment: If both quality and battlegroupname are strings, there is no way for the API to distinguish between the routes and it always match the first one found (i.e. the one with the quality parameter).